# dirtyJoe to manipulate java byte code

Tags: java, bytecode, bytecode-manipulation

I'm using Dirty Joe to manipulate this code bellow

```
SetAttribute localSetAttribute = new SetAttribute(140, "B", beeperVolume.getValue(), 0);
```

So I use Dirty Joe to change number to push. On code editor I only found edit opcode which only edit the memory address.

How I can modified number to push instead of memory address?
Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about the 140?

Answer (score 0):

It's not the memory address. To change the number 140 with 150, for instance, replace the last by 8C with 96:

[image]

Comment: How about 1664, is it sipush able to do that? because it support for short

Comment: @NPE that would be 06 80 if i'm not mistaken

Comment: How to copy method on dirty joe?

Comment: @NPE I don't know.